# Get Applied shopping cart price rule/Catalog price Rule name in product details page

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

I'm using magento 1.9. How to Get, Applied shopping cart price rule/Catalog price Rule name in product details page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like here...

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
->getQuote()
->getCouponCode();
```

Comment: Does this work for shopping cart price rules as well as coupon codes?